# Should there be a separate table when mapping one to many relationship?

Tags: mysql, sql

In terms of performance and scalability which one would be a better method to do one to many mappings in MySQL.

- Using a separate column but sticking to 2 tables:

  (person) :  id, name

  (phone) :  id, number, type, person_id
- Using a separate table:

  (person) :    id, name

  (phone) :    id, number, type

  (person_phone) :  id, person_id, phone_id

Comment: Under what circumstances do you imagine doing two joins to get to the data you need will be faster than doing a single join?

Comment: I mentioned performance and scabaility. I was wondering if having a separate table would make it more scalable.

Comment: @Dan: May be breaking schema on multiple database servers? [Warnings levels of caffeine achieved long time ago, so this might not be the best argument]

Comment: @Shoaibi How would that be related to creating extraneous tables? I don't see the connection.

Comment: Ok, under what circumstances do you imagine performing 2 joins will scale better than performing a single join?

Comment: BTW, you don't need an `id` in any of these tables except maybe `person`. Every table doesn't need an artificial identifier.

Comment: I was thinking along the lines like if there are say a billion records then we can potentially put all the tables on separate servers. Bailing out, may be wasn't a wisest question i have asked.

Comment: @Dan: Ya, could have gone with a composite key like (number, type, person_id). Dumb example.

Comment: More typically you scale across multiple databases through horizontal partitioning (put all users whose IDs are even on server 1, odd on server 2), not by table. You can't join a table on another server for one thing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's only one correct answer to this, and it's the first one.

The second of your ideas is how you model many-to-many relationships, not one-to-many.

Comment: the second one implies different people can share the same phone number, which is BS

Comment: It's "BS"? Huh, my wife and I have shared the same phone for years.

Comment: It's just an example, guys. His actual question is "when mapping one to many relationships". Keep calm :)

Comment: When my office first opened it was common for 4-6 developers to assigned 1 shared phone.  What the heck do the coders need to talk to people for right? ;)

Answer (score 5):

In terms of performance it is always cheaper to avoid joins, which add multiplicity to the amount of rows to be queried.

As long as a single phone will only be used by one employee (a true one-to-many) the first option is best.

Comment: Of course, there are tradeoffs in other areas with minimizing joins. Otherwise everyone would just use single-table databases (which isn't as ludicrous as it sounds... they once had a sizable following). But you are correct that adding `JOIN`s just to add them isn't going to do your performance any favors.

Answer (score 5):

First one is better.

1. Better performance.
2. Less storage space.
3. Easy to understand.

P.S. Maybe you even don't need `id` for phone, `(number, type, person_id)` is enough.

Comment: Too bad i can upvote only once, need one separate upvote for P.S. :)